# Disjoint union of topological space is subspace

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Suppose we have a space $X$ and a family of subspaces $(X_i)_{i \in I}$ for some index set $I$. Is there a way to see $\coprod_{i \in I} X_i$ as a subspace of $X$? There is the canonical map $\coprod_{i \in I} X_i \to X$, but is is not an injection in general.

Comment: Consider $X_1 = X_2 = \{a\}$ as subspaces of both $X = \{a\}$ and $Y = \{a,b\}$. Do these two examples help?

Comment: I could use the family $(\{a\})_{a \in \mathbb R}$  of subsets of $\mathbb R$.  Their disjoint union is not separable, so cannot be homeomorphic to a subspace of $\mathbb R$.